# How to rename audio file which is in sd card programmatically?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Here is my code to display all music file names in a list view ,here i am taking all files in an array list then displaying in a listview,by using contextmenu performing "rename" on listitems but these changes are not effecting actual file which is in sd card ,suggest me how to do this ,i tried file operations like this.

```
path = "/sdcard/";
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    }
    setTitle(path);
    // Read all files sorted into the values-array
    values = new ArrayList();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.canRead()) {
        setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
    }
    final String[] list = dir.list();
    if (list != null) {
        for (String file : list) {
            if (file.contains(".3gp")) {
                values.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(values);
    // Put the data into the list
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            android.R.id.text1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(myList);
}

final int CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE = 1;
final int CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME = 2;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "silmek");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME, Menu.NONE, "adını değiştirmek");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    Long id = myList.getAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
    final int number_of_item_in_listview = Integer.valueOf(id.intValue());
    final int context_menu_number = item.getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
```

This is how i am renaming file prgrammatically using contextmenu for listview

```
case CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME:

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("öğeyi yeniden adlandırmak");
        alert.setMessage("Seçili öğe için yeni bir isim girin");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("tamam",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                        String value = input.getText().toString();
                        values.set(number_of_item_in_listview, value
                                + ".3gp");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        /*
                         * File sdcard =
                         * Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); File
                         * from = new File(sdcard,"from.txt"); File to = new
                         * File(sdcard,"to.txt"); from.renameTo(to);
                         */
                        File f = new File(path + filename);
                        if (f != null && f.exists()) {
                            File from = new File(f, f.getName());
                            File to = new File(f, value);
                            from.renameTo(to);
                        }

                    }
                });

        alert.setNegativeButton("iptal",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                    }
                });
        alert.show();
        return (true);
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using File.renameTo() rather than running the mv command, since I'm fairly sure the latter isn't supported..

Have you given your application permission to write to the SD Card?

You do this by adding the following to your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If it doesn't work once the permission is added check the device log for errors when you try to rename the file (either using the adb command or in the logcat view in Eclipse).

When accessing the SD Card you shouldn't hard-code the path but instead use the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` method to get the directory.

The following code works for me:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File from = new File(sdcard,"from.txt");
File to = new File(sdcard,"to.txt");
from.renameTo(to);
```

Comment: i think same code Prabha using,?could you please check the code and update your answer..